# Setting a cookie before a redirect

Tags: php, cookies, redirect, header

I'm attempting to set a cookie just before a header redirect but it is not working.  I have read that setting the cookie after the header redirect line should solve the problem, but I am having no luck.  Similarly, a post here previously suggested that if you were using a 'human URL' in the location redirect, you should use '/' in the path parameter of the cookie.  This has also been done with no luck.

```
header("Location: $url" . $params);
setcookie('cartstlang', 'lang', 0, '/', '', FALSE, FALSE);
setcookie('cartstdb', 'db', 0, '/', '', FALSE, FALSE);
```

Also note, I have tested this by commenting out the header redirect and then clicking on an  link to change pages.  The cookies then appeared fine on a var_dump().

I am developing on XAMPP with PHP 5.3+.  I have tested in both IE 8 and Firefox 4.

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: hearder line should be after setcookie

Comment: I have heard the opposite too.  Either way, I have tried both the header before and after the setcookie call.

Comment: here is one claim that the order should be header -> setcookie: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#96251

Answer (score 2):

The `setcookie` code should come before the `header` code and make sure you do an `exit()` after to stop any output.

Also are you sure it's going to the same domain (there is a difference between http://site.com and http://www.site.com)? Try setting the domain option to `.site.com` in the `setcookie` so it can be accessed across all subdomains.

Comment: Actually, the header redirect goes to a different domain altogether. After some processing here, it then redirects back to my domain, and it is then that I am trying to use the cookie.

I cannot include an exit() after the redirect either, as the function it contains must return TRUE in order for some other important scripts to be run.  I have no control over this; I am writing a plugin and cannot change core functionality.

Comment: Well then your going to need to debug further. Check that the cookie is set in your browser before the redirect, then go to the page it would take you back and check the cookie is there.

Comment: I have checked that the cookie is set without the redirect, and I have also established that the cookie is not at the page where I require it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$value = 'something from somewhere';

setcookie("TestCookie", $value);




echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["TestCookie"];

// Another way to debug/test is to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

and post back the reply what do you see. Also make sure cookies are enabled.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: TestCookie in ....\waiting.php on line 3 Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_COOKIE_VARS in ...\waiting.php on line 3.

Cookies are enabled; they are set fine without attempting the header redierct.

Comment: Ignore the above, forgot to refresh.

something from somewhere
Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_COOKIE_VARS in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla_and_vm\waiting.php on line 2

Cookies are definately set. Thanks for the reply.