# URL redirection to different URL when I open the link for second time

Tags: php, redirect

Is it possible to redirect a URL (say https://www.click2redirect.com) to https://www.example1.com once (or when user opens the link on a browser for first time) and then when the same user with the same browser opens the same link i.e. https://www.click2redirect.com gets redirected to another URL https://www.example2.com, and never gets redirected to https://example1.com ever again, until and unless the cache or browsing history has been cleared.

I want to use php with it.

Thank you

Comment: Sure. Store a cookie in the browser and detect if its set or not.

Comment: can you help me with a little code or boilerplate, or can you provide me with a link to any related tutorial or documentation? I have never worked with cookies ever before. It would be a great favor

Comment: The documentation is a good place to start - https://www.php.net/setcookie

Comment: yes, it was really helpful. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a cookie before a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277032/setting-a-cookie-before-a-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

```
$isVisited = $_COOKIE['_ONCE_VISITED_'] ?? false;
if(!$isVisited) {
    // will expire in a year (should be fine)
    setcookie("_ONCE_VISITED_", true, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    header("Location: https://google.com");
}
```

try this. don't forget to add php start tag